# Allow EC2 instance to access S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've got an S3 bucket with a few files in. Public access disabled

I've also got an EC2 instance which I want to be able to access all files in the bucket.

I created a role with permissions like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I assigned the role to my EC2 instance, but I still get 403 forbidden if I try and access a file in the bucket from my EC2 instance.

Not sure what i've done wrong.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you accessing objects in this bucket? And, while on the EC2 instance, go to the shell and run `aws sts get-caller-identity`. Does it report credentials for the expected IAM role?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, get-caller-identity shows the correct role. I'm trying to access the object by its URL, i.e. https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/myfile

Comment: So you're accessing the file via HTTP and not the AWS SDK?  Have you enabled the S3 bucket to [host static websites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html)?

Comment: It's a private object. HTTP URLs require public access (unless you've created and are using a pre-signed URL). Use `aws s3 cp` (awscli) to copy the object locally using AWS credentials (or use an AWS SDK).

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense now. I was using wget in a script, but I should be able to swap that for the cli commands. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing private objects in an Amazon S3 bucket, it is necessary to provide authentication to prove that you are permitted to access the object.

It would appear that you are attempting to access the file *without* any authentication information, by simply accessing the URL:  `mybucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/myfile`

If you wish to access an object this way, you can create an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to a private object in Amazon S3. It appends a 'signature' to the URL to prove that you are authorised to access it.

Alternatively, you could access the object via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), or via the AWS SDK in your preferred programming language. This way, API requests will be authenticated against the S3 service.